Expansions of Jacobian Theta and Jacobian Elliptic Quotients
Let $\omega_2,\omega_1\in\mathbb C-\{0\}$ be such that $\tau=\omega_2/\omega_1\in \mathbb H$, $\wp(z)$ be the classical Weierstrass elliptic function with periods $\omega_1,\omega_2$ and take $\omega_3=\omega_1+\omega_2$. Let $e_j=\wp(\omega_j/2)$ be the classic half period values. Let $\theta,\theta_1,\theta_2,\theta_3$ denote the Jacobian theta functions with the notation used in Jordan's Course d'Analyse, which are most convenient to work with while doing Weierstrassian elliptic function theory. For convenience, we collect their definitions as follows since it is different than the classic one:
\begin{gather*}
\theta(z,\tau)=-i\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^n q^{\left( n+1/2 \right)^2}e^{(2n+1)\pi iz},\\
\theta_1(z,\tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{\left( n+1/2 \right)^2}e^{(2n+1)\pi iz},\\
\theta_2(z,\tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty} q^{n^2}e^{2n\pi iz},\\
\theta_3(z,\tau)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}(-1)^n q^{n^2}e^{2n\pi iz},\\
\end{gather*}
where $q=e^{i\pi\tau}$ is the usual nome. We omit the arguments for the nullwerte $\theta_j=\theta_j(0,\tau)$ and derivatives are always with respect to $z$. It is a standard result in elliptic function theory that
\begin{align*}
\wp(\omega_1z)-e_j=\frac{\theta'^2}{\omega_1^2 \theta_j^2}\frac{\theta_j^2(z,\tau)}{\theta^2(z,\tau)}.
\end{align*}
In Chandrasekharan's book Elliptic Functions, Taylor series of the odd function $\theta$ and even function $\theta_j$ are expanded, then the coefficient of $z^0$ is compared in both sides of this equation to obtain
\begin{align*}
e_j=\frac{1}{\omega_1^2}\left( \frac{1}{3}\frac{\theta'''}{\theta'}-\frac{\theta_j''}{\theta_j} \right).
\end{align*}
This formula is cruical to prove the Jacobi's identity $\theta'=\pi \theta_1\theta_2\theta_3$. I would like to use the Laurent expansion of Weierstrass' $\wp$ function to obtain further identities. It is well known that
\begin{align*}
\wp(z)=\frac{1}{z^2}+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} (2k+1)G_{2k+2} z^{2k}
\end{align*}
in a neighbourhood of $z=0$ where $G_{2k}=\sum_{(m,n)\neq 0}(m\omega_1+n\omega_2)^{-2k}$ are the familiar Eisentein series. Comparing the coefficient of $z^{2k-2}$, we must have a relation of form
\begin{align*}
G_{2k}=\frac{1}{\omega_1^{2k}}f_k\left( \begin{array}{c} \theta',\theta''',\ldots,\theta^{(2n-1)},\ldots\\ \theta_j,\theta''_j,\ldots,\theta^{(2n)}_j,\ldots \end{array} \right) \qquad \text{or}\qquad G_{2k}(\tau)=f_k\left( \begin{array}{c} \theta',\theta''',\ldots,\theta^{(2n-1)},\ldots\\ \theta_j,\theta''_j,\ldots,\theta^{(2n)}_j,\ldots \end{array} \right)
\end{align*}
must hold for every $k$ and $j$. For example, if i am not mistaken in my calculations we have
\begin{align*}
\omega_1^4G_{4}=\frac{1}{3}\frac{\theta_j^{(4)}}{\theta_j}+\frac{1}{12}\frac{\theta_j''^2}{\theta_j^2}+\frac{1}{36}\frac{\theta'''^2}{\theta'^2}-\frac{1}{9}\frac{\theta_j''}{\theta_j}\frac{\theta'''}{\theta'}-\frac{1}{180}\frac{\theta^{(5)}}{\theta'}.
\end{align*}
Similarly, we may obtain analogous formula for $G_6$ and use $G_{2k}\in \mathbb Q[G_4,G_6]$ (A simple consequence of Weierstrass' differential equation and Laurent expansion of $\wp$) to get further identities. But the simple method of slapping Taylor series for $\theta,\theta_j$ and multiplying out is not satisfactory. Even though there is an enormous literature for $\theta$-functions i am yet to see a formula of interest here. I have looked at W.W. Modern Analysis, Abramowitz and Stegun, Higher Transcendental Functions, Gradshteyn and Rhyzik, Byrd Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Scientists just to name a few. The quantity $\wp(z)-e_j$ is related to Jacobi's elliptic functions too. Denote $\gamma=\sqrt{e_1-e_3}$, it is a classic result that
\begin{align*}
\wp(z)=e_1+\gamma^2\text{cs}^2\left( \gamma z,k \right)=e_2+\gamma^2\text{ds}^2\left( \gamma z,k \right)=e_3+\gamma^2\text{ns}^2\left( \gamma z,k \right)
\end{align*}
where we have used Glaisher-Gudermann compact notation and $k=\sqrt{\frac{e_2-e_3}{e_1-e_3}}$. So it suffices to consider the expansions of $\text{cs}^2, \text{ds}^2, \text{ns}^2$. Which do not seem to exist in closed form in the literature. So we turn to $\text{cn},\text{dn},\text{ns}$. Most of the books in the literature contains the Taylor expansions of these functions for a few terms. Yet a closed form still does not seem to exist. For example, Byrd notes the expansions
\begin{align*}
\text{cn}(z,k)=1-\frac{z^2}{2!}+\left( 1+4k^2 \right)\frac{z^4}{4!}-\left( 1+44k^2+16k^4 \right)\frac{z^6}{6!}+\left( 1+408k^2+912k^4+64k^6 \right)\frac{z^8}{8!}+\ldots\\
\text{dn}(z,k)=1-k^2\frac{z^2}{2!}+\left(4k^2+k^4 \right)\frac{z^4}{4!}-\left( 16k^2+44k^4+k^6 \right)\frac{z^6}{6!}+\left( 64+912k^2+408k^4+k^6 \right)\frac{z^8}{8!}+\ldots\\
\text{ns}(z,k)=\frac{1}{z}+\left( 1+k^2 \right)\frac{z}{6}+\left( 7-22k^2+7k^4 \right)\frac{z^3}{360}+\left( 31-15k^2-15k^4+31k+6 \right)\frac{z^5}{15120}+\ldots
\end{align*}
which are valid in a certain neighbourhood of $z=0$.
To summarize, is there a closed form for the Taylor coefficients of any of the functions:
\begin{align*}
\frac{\theta^2}{\theta_j^2},\text{cs}^2, \text{ds}^2, \text{ns}^2,\text{cn},\text{dn},\text{ns}.
\end{align*}

Amazing information. +1
